# Edits are lost when accidentally pressing back or screen lock goes on on Android app

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

This is really giving me a hard time: When I edit an answer or comment inside the Android app, as soon as I hit the back button on the top left I lose everything I changed. This very same workflow works when writing fresh answers or comments.

More problematic: I lose everything I edited as soon as the lock screen goes on.

Comment: Partly repro'd on v1.0.84 beta: 1) While editing an answer, an answer draft will be created when going back to previous screen. 2) Comments will always be gone. 3) Lock screen doesn't affect this issue on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1. For 2), I guess some sort of confirmation dialog will be good enough when a comment box is not empty.